# Multiprocessing functions for dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, pool

I have an excel sheet which consists of 2 columns. The first keywords and the second is Url.

I am making a script to extract groups which shares the same 3 URLs or more.

I wrote the below code but it takes around an hour to process the main function on a huge excel sheet.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
```

```
loop = 1
numerator = 0
continuee= []
df_list = []
for index in list(df.sort_values('Url').set_index('Url').index.unique()):
    if len(df.sort_values('Url').set_index('Url').loc[index].values) == 1:
        list1 = list(df.sort_values('Url').set_index('Url').loc[index].values)
    elif len(df.sort_values('Url').set_index('Url').loc[index].keywords.values) > 1:
        list1 = list(df.sort_values('Url').set_index('Url').loc[index].keywords.values)
    df1 = df[df.keywords.isin(list1)]
    df1 = df1[df1.Url.duplicated(keep=False)]
    df1 = df1.groupby('Url').filter(lambda x: x.Url.value_counts() == df1.keywords.nunique())
    df1 = df1.groupby('keywords').filter(lambda x: x.keywords.value_counts() >= 3)
    df1 = df1.groupby('Url').filter(lambda x: x.Url.value_counts() == df1.keywords.nunique())
    if df1.keywords.nunique() > 1:
        silos = list(df1.keywords.unique())
        df_list.append({numerator:silos})
        word = word[~(word.isin(silos))]
        numerator += 1
    else:
        singles = list(word[word.keywords.isin(list1)].keywords.unique())
        df_list.append({"single" : singles})
        word = word[~(word.isin(singles))]
    print(loop)
    loop += 1
trial = pd.DataFrame(df_list)
if 'single' in list(trial.columns):
    for i in list(word.keywords.unique()):
        if i not in list(trial.single):
            df_list.append({"single" : i})
else:
    for i in list(word.keywords.unique()):
        df_list.append({"single" : i})
trial = pd.DataFrame(df_list)
```

I tried many times to use multiprocessing but I failed as I am not really getting how it works with Pandas. Is there a way to help me, please? Also, if I wanted to pass another couple of functions how would I do it? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what your raw dataframe looks like?

Comment: not really clear about your question. But why cant you just filter out each columns like df[df[col1]==df['col1]]

Comment: @AhmedElsawy edit the original comment with the example df and desired output.

Comment: My dataframe looks like this,

Keywords | Url
------------- | ----
"how to connect hose to 8-cia sump pump" : https://homeguides.sfgate.com/repair-little-giant-sump-pump-84505.html
I am not sure if this has something to do with the multiprocessing or not, but please note that my problem is to multiprocess the df and not within the function functionality itself. I am sorry, I am not sure how to represent dataframes in the comments, I am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather, this should be your solution;

```
by_size = df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size().reset_index()
three_or_more=by_size[by_size[0]>=3].iloc[:,:-1]
```

Example:

```
>>> df
   keyword  url
0        2    2
1        4    3
2        2    1
3        4    3
4        1    1
5        2    1
6        4    1
7        2    1
8        1    1
9        3    3
>>> by_size = df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size().reset_index()
>>> by_size
   keyword  url  0
0        1    1  2
1        2    1  3
2        2    2  1
3        3    3  1
4        4    1  1
5        4    3  2
>>> three_or_more=by_size[by_size[0]>=3].iloc[:,:-1]
>>> three_or_more
   keyword  url
1        2    1
```

Comment: I am sorry if my question isn't clear. I am asking for a way to apply pool multiprocessing for the above function. It took one hour to run on a 90K rows excel file, I need to use all the processing threads to make it work faster.

Comment: I understand multiprocessing is what you think the solution is, but that is not the case. The above operation has an average execution time of 0.12 seconds when tested against a 1million row dataset. I suggest trying the solution given, then come back if it's too slow.

Comment: The code you provided doesn't work the way I want, mate. I want to extract each group that shares the same 3 Urls or more in another column or in a different dataframe. It produces the best results but I don't want know how to optimize it or write it in sqlite3 as I believe it'd make it faster

Comment: @AhmedElsawy so for every url that has 3 or more occurances, you want to extract all keywords / rows which have that url?

Comment: Not just one URL. 3 URLs. The dataframe contains a keyword multiple times, and in front of each duplicated is a URL that. I need to extract each group of words that has in front of it 3 similar URLs or more